TextLayoutResult.getOffsetForPosition() return bad values in Compose Desktop
I am trying to setup a composable that gives me the actual hovered character of its text. To do this, initially I configured hover ability by defining the onPointerEvent modifier for a standard Text composable (and defined its type to PointerEventType.Move as well).
Before getting the hovered character I retrieved the actual TextLayoutResult value generated by the related Text composable and, using this layout result, I got access to the function getOffsetForPosition(), that receives the hover offset.
This would be fine to do my job, however, when hovering I get bad results. The easiest scenario is when we hover a letter "m". Due to its relatively large width, sometimes the code returns the side character instead.
This is my reproduceable code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyHoveredText(
  content: AnnotatedString = buildAnnotatedString { },
  onCharacterHovered: (Char?) -> Unit = {}
) {
  // stores the resulting layout
  val layoutResult = remember { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null) }

  Text(
    text = content,
    onTextLayout = {
      layoutResult.value = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier.onPointerEvent(eventType = PointerEventType.Move) {
      val hoverPosition = it.changes.first().position
      layoutResult.value?.let { layoutResult ->
        val characterOffset = layoutResult.getOffsetForPosition(position = hoverPosition)
        runCatching {
          onCharacterHovered(content[characterOffset])
        }.onFailure {
          onCharacterHovered(null)
        }
      }
    }
  )
}

/**
 * Auxiliary composable only to call/test the above one.
 */
@Composable
fun AuxMyHoveredTextCaller() {
  // stores the actual targeted character found by the hovering
  var currentHoveredCharacter by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

  Column {
    MyHoveredText(
      content = buildAnnotatedString {
        append(
          """
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed venenatis diam ut metus placerat, ac accumsan libero posuere. Fusce tristique cursus dui, blandit laoreet risus hendrerit in. Phasellus semper laoreet finibus. In vitae est rhoncus, eleifend elit lacinia, venenatis leo. Morbi nibh est, egestas ut est et, vestibulum dignissim urna. Proin sit amet urna id magna elementum pretium. Aliquam eleifend scelerisque tortor, eget tincidunt magna faucibus in. Sed vel justo sed sem consequat blandit quis hendrerit erat. Vestibulum blandit, odio nec ornare laoreet, elit dolor ultrices eros, a ullamcorper tortor sapien ut orci. Vestibulum viverra elementum risus a finibus. Aenean tincidunt nibh lectus, non eleifend mi pretium in. Cras diam diam, consequat in nunc ut, accumsan maximus erat.
          """.trimIndent()
        )
      },
      onCharacterHovered = {
        currentHoveredCharacter = it?.toString() ?: "null"
      }
    )

    Text(text = "Hovered character: [$currentHoveredCharacter]", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
  }
}

Based on this, is there any way to handle this problem or is it a real issue related to the library?
Fore reference, this is an issue shared in the official compose-multiplatform repository
